# Spring Boot Actuator lock-out policy implementaion

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

In the Spring Boot Reference Guide it is mentioned that Spring Boot Actuator can be used "to implement lock-out policy based on authentication failures".
Is there any code example how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. You would need to implement an `AuditListener` or an `AuditEventRepository` (easier the latter) and use it to count successive authentication failures.